# Ubuntu 19.10 Snap performance issues

Tags: thunderbird, snap, ubuntu-core, desktop-apps

Now that it looks like more default apps are using the snap versions, a number of issues cause a decline in the experience:

1. Startup of the apps is slower.
2. Snap apps don't interact with other apps: e.g. Thunderbird attachments don't open in default apps. You have to save them first.
3. Non-English language input doesn't work in snaps.

Where is the correct place to report/follow these bugs? And what is the development plan for snaps?

Thanks

Comment: See [ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). That includes information about how to search Launchpad for bug reports. We also have [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121) Your question about the "development plan for snaps" seems either vague or very broad, but I think a specific question about how snaps are developed *might* be answerable. Bug reporting and [some Ubuntu+1 stuff *late* in the development cycle](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/871/22949) are on-topic, but questions about the details of bugs in Ubuntu+1 are likely to be viewed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 19.10 is an early release unstable build; it is almost impossible to *not* run into issues with it. It is *highly* recommended you opt for 19.04 instead, as it is more stable, and has the more available software and the same kernel version (5). Snapcraft has it's own Q&A forum available at https://forum.snapcraft.io/. Consider asking your question here instead of AskUbuntu, as you will likely get more appropriate help to resolve your issue faster.

Comment: The forum is a good place for most of this feedback. However, I would add that it might be better report (some of) these issues to the app developers directly.

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake and it was actually 19.04, but I will move to the snapcraft forum in any case. Thank you!